# JOptionPanel.showMessageDialog doesn't show up when program is run through the .jar file

Tags: java, file, jar, embedded-resource

I did a little bit of searching around for the answer to my question, but didn't find anything that quite matched mine, maybe I didn't search hard enough, but I'm new to this site.

So I use NetBeans IDE 8.0.2, and when I run my program through the IDE, everything works fine. But when I run it through its Executable Jar file, I get the first 2 input boxes, but the final alert doesn't come up.

The program simply takes in 2 names (player) from input, then assigns each one a team to use in Fifa, taken from an external list called, "teams.txt". I made it for me and my roommates to use when we play Fifa 19 and we want to use random teams, but don't want to get stuck with a 1-2 star team.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> teams = new ArrayList<>();

    // Read file, then store each new line item in the ArrayList.
    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("teams.txt"));

        while (s.hasNext()) {
            teams.add(s.nextLine());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
    }

    // Take user input from dialog box and store it in variables player1 and player2.
    String player1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Player 1: Enter your name.");
    String player2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Player 2: Enter your name.");
    //Print the values given in the Java console.
    System.out.println("Player 1: " + player1);
    System.out.println("Player 2: " + player2);

    // Random team generator within dialog box.
    Random r = new Random();
    String msg1 = player1 + ": " + teams.get(r.nextInt(teams.size()));
    String msg2 = player2 + ": " + teams.get(r.nextInt(teams.size()));
    Component frame = null;
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("icon2.png");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, msg1 + "\n" + msg2, "Fifa Team Picker", PLAIN_MESSAGE, icon);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot read individual .jar file entries as files, because they are not separate files.  They are just subsequences of bytes indicating compressed data.  This means your Scanner is failing, and your `teams` collection is empty, which in turn causes `teams.get` to throw an exception.

If you run the .jar file on the command line, you can see this for yourself.  Such a command typically looks like:  `java -jar myteamsproject.jar`

A file that is part of your application is called a *resource.*  You must read it with the [getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) or [getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) method of Class:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("teams.txt"));
```

Similarly, you must pass a resource as a URL to ImageIcon, rather than a filename:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("icon2.png"));
```

Of course, the above lines will not work unless teams.txt and icon2.png are actually in the .jar file.  When the .jar file is built, you should examine its contents and verify that those entries are present.